# Autologin during development with Jetty

Tags: jetty, autologin

I have the usual setup: A webapp with a login screen and a small Java class which sets up Jetty to launch the app.

During development, we all waste a couple of seconds to log in after every change to the code which forces a restart. (No, [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) doesn't help since it doesn't run the constructors again so it can miss some changes).

So I was wondering if I could patch the Jetty setup in such a way:

If I request `/index.jsp`, instead of going to the real JSP, it should load a servlet which fills in the username and password of the typical development user, logs him in, and then redirects to the main JSP of the app.

To make everything safe, I'll put this auto-login code into the test path, so it can't be deployed accidentally.

Now the question: How do I configure URL redirection/rewriting in Jetty from Java code? For obvious reasons, I don't want to touch `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the examples in , I came up with this code:

```
private WebAppContext webapp;

private void configureAutoLogin() {
    ServletHolder holder = webapp.getServletHandler().newServletHolder();
    holder.setName("autologin");
    holder.setClassName( AutoLoginServlet.class.getName() );

    webapp.getServletHandler().addServlet(holder);

    ServletMapping mapping = new ServletMapping();
    mapping.setServletName(holder.getName());
    String[] paths = { "/autologin" };
    mapping.setPathSpecs( paths );

    webapp.getServletHandler().addServletMapping(mapping);
}
```

To make it more simple for users, I also created a directory `jetty/` which contains a `test.html` where developers can add links to such URLs. To make sure this test HTML page can't be deployed accidentally, I add the `jetty/` directory to the base resource of the `WebAppContext`:

```
    File webAppDir = new File( "src/main/webapp" );
    Resource webAppResource = new FileResource( webAppDir.toURI().toURL() );
    Resource jettyDir = new FileResource( new File( "jetty" ).toURI().toURL() );

    ResourceCollection resources = new ResourceCollection( webAppResource, jettyDir );
    webapp.setBaseResource( resources );
```